# Is there a design pattern for this?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I have a component that needs to call a specific service depending on the input it receives. So my component has to look at the input and based on a configuration that says "for this input call this service with this data" needs to call the proper service. The services have a common signature method and a specific one (each).

I thought about an abstract class that includes the signatures for all three methods. The implementation for the two services will override all three methods (throwing `NotImplementedException` for the methods that are not supported by current service). A component that could be initialized with a map (that for each input type will have the type of the service to be called) will also be defined.

Do you have a better approach to cope this scenario ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Factory pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) has this definition:

> Define an interface for creating an
>   object, but let subclasses decide
>   which class to instantiate. Factory
>   Method lets a class defer
>   instantiation to subclasses

Sounds like what you want, right?

Comment: I thought (tagged) about the factory DP, but in this case it has to be combined with some other pattern, in order to be "configurable". I was asking for an existing approach in this way.

Comment: Also, this could be associated with the Singleton or Object pooling pattern

Comment: The facade or adapter pattern may be worthy ones to consider in allowing some configuration I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft calls this The [Provider Model Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx).  Although since your methods do not implement all methods perhaps it isn't a great fit.

[At its most basic level the pattern is:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972370.aspx)

> - An abstract base class defining a
>     contract. The abstract base class has
>     all the abstract methods and
>     properties required to implement the
>     public API it supports.
> - Configuration information. Once an
>     implementation of the feature provider
>     class is created, it must be described
>     in the configuration section. The description of the provider within configuration provides all the information so that the provider can be instantiated in the running application.

The abstract base class usually should support factory methods to create new objects.

Answer (score 0):

The Strategy design pattern is well suited for your problem. 
A strategy encapsulates an algorithm and that needs to be executed depending on the type of data you have as input.